# How to run Powershell as an Admin yet execute functions as a Standard user?

Tags: powershell, certificate

I have a PowerShell script that has a function that deletes a certificate based on certain values in the Subject. This function works but only if I run the commands in a normal PowerShell window. If I run the PowerShell as an admin with separate admin credentials it fails.

The reason it fails is because when my script gets to the function where PowerShell parses the Personal Store of the Current User, it checks under the admin account running the script and not the current user itself. Is it possible to fix this within the Function itself?

Can I tell PowerShell to check the Currently Logged in Users Personal certificate Store and not the certificate store of the Admin user that is executing the script?

Unfortunately I need admin credentials to execute PowerShell scripts. I can't run them locally with my normal account.

```
function deleteCert(){
    try {
        Write-Host "Deleting Some Certificate..."
        $cert = Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\CurrentUser\My -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Subject -Like "*Some Certificate*"}
        if($cert -eq $null){
            Write-Host "Unable to locate Certificate"
        }else{
            Remove-Item $cert
            Write-Host "Deleting Some Certificate Successful..."
        }
        
    }catch {
        Write-Error "Exception caught in removing certificate"
        Exit
    }
}
```

Comment: A solution I'm aware of is using a task scheduler. Set it to run under the user logged in, and have it run as your admin

Comment: Why do you need admin credentials to execute PowerShell scripts?

Comment: I was able to actually get permission to run the script with non-admin level permissions so I am all set not. The reason we have that enabled is for security reasons.

Comment: As an aside, I would point out that preventing PowerShell or cmd.exe from running does _not_ increase security. (Being able to run PowerShell and/or does not grant magical admin powers. This is because PowerShell and/or cmd.exe are _programs_, not security boundaries.) The same caveat applies to arbitrarily preventing PowerShell scripts from running (i.e., the fact that a user can run a PowerShell script does not grant said user magical admin powers).